# c#: Return a stream on Web API core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET web API server written with C# (v2.2). One of my exposed methods, creating a `MemoryStream` and adding data into it. In the end, return it with the `return File(ms)` method.

My code looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("my-endpoint")]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestMe()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    await sw.WriteLineAsync($"A,B,C").ConfigureAwait(false);
    await sw.WriteLineAsync($"1,2,3").ConfigureAwait(false);
    await sw.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(ms, "application/csv");
}
```

The problem here is that this code not disposing all the stream from the memory for sure. In case that everything was OK, the stream will be closed by the ASP.NET code. If an exception was thrown, the stream won't be disposed.

I thought that the right way to implement it will be (this code is NOT working):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("my-endpoint")]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestMe()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        await sw.WriteLineAsync($"A,B,C").ConfigureAwait(false);
        await sw.WriteLineAsync($"1,2,3").ConfigureAwait(false);
        await sw.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return File(ms, "application/csv");
    }
}
```

The problem here is when we are leaving the function (on the `return` line). Then, the stream will be disposed before being returned to the client.

How to make my code work safely?

Comment: When you talk about an exception being thrown do you mean in the `TestMe` method or in the asp.net framework?

Comment: A MemoryStream is just a wrapper over a `byte[]`. You shouldn't worry about disposing it.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` is useless in ASP.NET Core applications as there's no synchronization context to return to. You won't get deadlocks the way you would in a desktop application or ASP.NET application

Comment: @Sean, I'm worried about my code (testme method).

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever - There's no need to worry. Your method just allocates memory, not underlying resources like files, so if something goes wrong the GC will collect the memory. Even if you were calling `Dispose` nothing is really happening as it's just memory you've allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your first method. If the code throws (either in your method or in the asp.net framework) then eventually the stream and writer will be garbage collected.

If nothing goes from then the `File` class will call `Dispose` on the memory stream, but as this is just a wrapper over a `byte` array nothing will really happen until the garbage collector kicks in, so either way your code is fine.

Comment: I thought it's a bad practice to avoid disposing of unused steams. Depending on GC sounds wired to me. You are sure about this?

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever - it all depends on the context. In this case it is fine.